# LINQ In Clause With Group By And TOP N Records Within Each Group

Tags: c#, .net, linq, group-by

I have 2 classes as below. If I had a generic list of class Schedule like List how would I write a LINQ query such that I can get all items within this List where SourceId matches 1,2,3...X and StartTime > some date time and then I want to return top 3 elements for each SourceId (ie: group by SourceId)

Since this List would be containing huge number of records, I want to write the most efficient LINQ query

Also I want the final shape of result to be in the form of List

```
public class Source
{
    public int SourceId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Schedule
{
    public int SourceId { get; set; }
    public Source Source { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

after hours of googling:

```
var result = r.ScheduleList.
             Where(s => sourceIdIntArray.Contains(s.SourceId) &&
                   s.StartTime >= new DateTime(2011, 09, 20)).
             GroupBy(s => s.SourceId).
             SelectMany(g => g.OrderBy(s => s.StartTime).
                             Take(3)).
             ToList();
```

Comment: This was really useful in optimizing my Linq query. :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that:

- no 2 sources have the same source Id
- you want the top 3 elements ordered by StartTime
- you're ok with having a `List<KeyValuePair<int,Schedule>`> as your result (top 3 grouped by Source Id and still returned as a list)

  ```
  IEnumerable<Schedule> schedules;
  DateTime someDateTime; // date time used for comparison
  IEnumerable<int> sourceIds; // required matching source Ids

  schedules.OrderBy(x=>x.StartTime)
  .Where(x => x.StartTime > someDateTime)
  .GroupBy(x=>x.Source.SourceId)
  .Where(x=>sourceIds.Contains(x.Key))
  .ToDictionary(x=>x.Key, x=>x.Take(3))
  .ToList()
  ```